# How can I fix these issues with nodes in tikz-qtree?

Tags: tikz-trees

How can I accomplish the following things?

- Nodes need to be same size.
- Get rid of thicker lines caused by overlapping.
- Get the finished state below state (aligned).

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
{draw,
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)
-- +(0,-8pt)
-| (\tikzchildnode)}}}
\Tree 
[.\node[draw]{State}; 
    [.\node[draw]{StandingUp};]
    [.\node[draw]{Searching}; 
        [.\node[draw, text width=25mm, align=center, text height=3mm]{SearchRotate};] 
        [.\node[draw, text width=25mm, align=center, text height=3mm]{Detecting};] 
    ]
    [.\node[draw]{Finished};]
    [.\node[draw]{Approaching}; 
        [.\node[draw]{Walking};]
        [.\node[draw]{ApproachRotate};]
    ]
    [.\node[draw]{Fallen};]
]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Are you joined at the hip to `tikz-qtree`? It would be easy in Forest, for example. For the sizing, you need to apply a standard `text width`, `text depth` and `text height` to all nodes if they should all have the same size.

Comment: @cfr I'm free to use any other packages ;) Can you provide an example? It might help other people as well.

Comment: Sure. Forest can also calculate the correct values for the width, depth and height which makes the structure of the tree more compact/efficient. (And Forest can do very compact trees, if that's what you want.) See below for a very compact and a spacier version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This first solution requires Forest v.2 or later. If you have an earlier version and cannot update, see below for an alternative which works with v.1.

Here's a Forest solution. The code parses the tree to determine the maximum depth, width and height of the nodes' contents. These values are then used to set the `text width`, `text depth` and `text height` for all nodes in the tree. The `edges` Forest library is used for the `forked edges` option.

Once the sizes are standardised, the middle child automatically aligns with its parent.

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={
    draw,
    text centered,
  },
  before typesetting nodes={
    tempdima/.max={width(content())}{root,tree},
    tempdimb/.max={height(content())}{root,tree},
    tempdimc/.max={depth(content())}{root,tree},
    for tree={
      text width/.register=tempdima,
      text height/.register=tempdimb,
      text depth/.register=tempdimc,
    }
  }
  [State
      [StandingUp]
      [Searching
          [SearchRotate]
          [Detecting]
      ]
      [Finished]
      [Approaching
          [Walking]
          [ApproachRotate]
      ]
      [Fallen]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Forest tree solution]

If a less compact tree is desired, add `fit=rectangle` or `fit=band` to the options for the tree. For example,

```
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={
    draw,
    text centered,
    fit=band,
  },
  before typesetting nodes={
    tempdima/.max={width(content())}{root,tree},
    tempdimb/.max={height(content())}{root,tree},
    tempdimc/.max={depth(content())}{root,tree},
    for tree={
      text width/.register=tempdima,
      text height/.register=tempdimb,
      text depth/.register=tempdimc,
    }
  }
  [State
      [StandingUp]
      [Searching
          [SearchRotate]
          [Detecting]
      ]
      [Finished]
      [Approaching
          [Walking]
          [ApproachRotate]
      ]
      [Fallen]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

produces a tree which is spread out further

[image: spacier tree]

## EDIT (for Forest v.1)

It is a bit more work to do this with earlier versions of Forest and the way I've done it requires a few TeX dimensions, but similar results are certainly possible:

[image: trees with Forest v.1]

The main problem is not the lack of the `edges` library - this can easily be emulated - but the complications caused by the lack of `register`s, introduced in v.2, and the need to substitute for the `.max` handler.

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\newdimen\statenodeswidth
\newdimen\statenodesheight
\newdimen\statenodesdepth
\forestset{%
  declare dimen={node width}{0pt},
  declare dimen={node height}{0pt},
  declare dimen={node depth}{0pt},
  declare dimen={nodes width}{0pt},
  declare dimen={nodes height}{0pt},
  declare dimen={nodes depth}{0pt},
  my forked edges/.style={
    for tree={
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- ++(0,-5pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
      },
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
    },
  },
  state tree/.style={
    my forked edges,
    for tree={
      draw,
      text centered,
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      for tree={
        node width/.pgfmath={width(content())},
        node height/.pgfmath={height(content())},
        node depth/.pgfmath={depth(content())},
        if={node_width()>\statenodeswidth}{
          TeX/.wrap pgfmath arg={\statenodeswidth=##1pt}{node_width()}
        }{},
        if={node_height()>\statenodesheight}{
          TeX/.wrap pgfmath arg={\statenodesheight=##1pt}{node_height()}
        }{},
        if={node_depth()>\statenodesdepth}{
          TeX/.wrap pgfmath arg={\statenodesdepth=##1pt}{node_depth()}
        }{},
      },
      delay={
        for tree={
          text width=\statenodeswidth,
          text height=\statenodesheight,
          text depth=\statenodesdepth,
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  state tree,
  for tree={
    fit=band,
  }
  [State
      [StandingUp]
      [Searching
          [SearchRotate]
          [Detecting]
      ]
      [Finished]
      [Approaching
          [Walking]
          [ApproachRotate]
      ]
      [Fallen]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  state tree,
  [State
      [StandingUp]
      [Searching
          [SearchRotate]
          [Detecting]
      ]
      [Finished]
      [Approaching
          [Walking]
          [ApproachRotate]
      ]
      [Fallen]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks great! am I supposed to modify tempdima, tempdimb and tempdimc? I'm currently getting errors when compiling it: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/574e44b00c338a4e540774e1

Comment: Possibly ShareLaTeX only has version 1 of Forest, whereas this code needs version 2. Do you know which version of TeX Live they're using? I'd know for sure if this is the problem if you say which error you get. (The first one is usually what matters.)

Comment: @user1534664 Yes, ShareLaTeX has an old version of Forest: `(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/forest/forest.sty
Package: forest 2015/07/15 v1.0.10 Drawing (linguistic) trees`.

Comment: I'm using sharelatex cause I'm working in a group, so I can't really go with texmaker for example. But I'll just use your diagram as an image. Perhaps less ideal but it's okay ;) Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You could upload the CTAN package Forest to your ShareLaTeX project.

Comment: @user1534664 Please see edit above for a version which works with Forest v.1. Hopefully, this should work with ShareLaTeX.

Comment: Thank you, it still looks amazing. You're like a latex god ;)

Comment: @user1534664 If only that were true! I can't imagine gods get frustrated by errors and recalcitrant code quite so frequently ;). But if anybody is a LaTeX god, it should be Forest's author - not me!